# How to organize views in multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

We are creating a mobile hybrid app using kendoui mobile framework and icenium. I know it is a one page-app with lots of views in it. However if we add a lot of views index.html can get very big and hard to maintain. I wonder if there is a way to organize views into  individual files and the include them into main page somehow. Something similar to partial views in asp.net. I cannot find a way of doing it, maybe there is some js library that does it?

Comment: @gumballhead Yes, I actualy use require.js to organise my javascript files, but not sure how to do same for html files, so my index.html will act like a master page and it will reference different views from separate html or js files...

Comment: Ah, then you can use the text plugin for html/css.  https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: @gumballhead So for each js file that serves view, I can load corresponding view from html file? Can you add your comment to answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS has a [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for this purpose.  With it, you can load html, templates, or other text files in the same way you would your Javascript dependencies.  A contrived example:

```
define([
  "lib/underscore",
  "lib/backbone",  
  "text!views/template.html"
], 

function (_, Backbone, template) {
  return Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template(template),

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an external library to achieve this. Kendo supports this out of the box using a feature called **remote views**. You can have main view in index.html and other views in other.html files. See documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#remote-views

Just add the file name (including path) in which your remote view is defined **without** # .

Comment: But this is only for navigation, how do I achieve it for page parts on the master page, like footer and header that need to be loaded all the time?

Comment: The header and footer you define in your index.html as a layout. You just need to assign this layout to the views in other .html files. Even though the views are in other html files, there is no difference between views defined in your initial page and them. Try to use the layout defined in this demo ("mobile-view" defined at the bottom). Now create a view in page.html, assign its layout as "mobile-view" and try to call it as remote view. You can see that the layout will be applied to the view in page.html.Still its not clear for you, let me know, I can create a POC and send it to you.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: You can download a working sample from this link: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=74A76F2473AFFE7F!527&authkey=!AIyF2IePmHyhrLc . Open the sample in safari if you are directly opening index.html using file:// . In chrome it may not work. if you host the pages as a website, it will work in chrome and you can test using ripple emulator. One the app is loaded, click the middle button in the tab strip which loads Theatres.html which has a view which is in a different physical file and shares the same layout as that of index.html

Comment: Yes, this is not really what I am after. As I said, your code only embeds files during navigation. What if I wanted to have my home page html in separate html, and my bottom menu html contents in a   separate html file for better maintainability? Solution given by gumballhead really does work with addition of a simple plugin (text.js)

Comment: Oh may be I misread your question. Again, this can be achieved in Kendo way. You can use Kendo templates for this. You can keep your kendo templates in separate JS files and load and render them using jQuery in to header and footer as and when required. You can keep a separate JS file for all your templates. We have done this and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

you can use RequireJS, i haven't use it but i know you can use, i have this code

```
// The view Loader. Used to asynchronously load views located in separate .html files
    window.templateLoader = {

    load: function(views, callback) {

        var deferreds = [];

        $.each(views, function(index, view) {
            if (uknowLocate.Views[view]) {
                deferreds.push($.get('js/templates/' + view + '.php', function(data) {
                    uknowLocate.Views[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
                }, 'html'));
            } else {
                console.error(view + " not found");
            }
        });

        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
    }

};
```

and i use it in this way:

```
uknowLocate.init = function () {
    templateLoader.load(['HomeView', 'MainMenuView',
        'GeofencesNewView',
        'CheckinOnetimeView','CheckinScheduledView','CheckinNewView','CheckinRecurrentView',
        'LocationhistoryView'], function () {
        app = new uknowLocate.Routers.ApplicationRouter();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState:false, root:'/project/folder/'});
    });
};
```

And in this way i load my templates, this is for Backbone, you can take the idea